# Ports to open for FTP II 7.5 Publish Servicing?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, ftp

Recently setup an ftp server using FTP 7.5 publishing service... I have tried opening ports 20,21 and that sort of worked but it hang after logging in.... saying Opening binary.....

I disabled the firewall and all works ok... So i tried following this document 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/

but it fails to work, can anyone tell me what i am missing?

I have specifically done this as per the document above

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FTP for IIS7" service=ftpsvc action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in

netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp disable
```

and set port channel range to 49152-65535..

As i say as per the document it FAILS won't even log in ... as if there is not ftp service there, with my GUESS opening port 20-21 TCP it sort of works but stops at opening binary.....

If i disabled the firewall completely that it works 100% without problems..

I am using Windows 7 (similar firewall setup to Windows 2008 server)

Any ideas really appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IIS predefined rules for FTP and only apply

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a statefull filtering issue, i think you should enable this feature in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Is FTP enabled for the private or public profile?